# Trying to join two arrays with different dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I'm learning python and I have 2 arrays:

```
a = [[ 1 , 2 ]
      [3,  4]]
b = [ 6,7]
```

when I print the shapes I get:

```
a.shape = (2,2)
b.shape = (2,)
```

want result to be:

```
c = [[ 1, 2 , 6]
     [3, 4, 7]]
```

I've tried

```
c = a + b
```

and

```
c = np.concatenate((a, b),axis=None) #tried axis=0, axis=1
```

I keep getting errors like

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: b should be b = [6,7] to start with.

Comment: So, did you try to correct the number of dimensions?  One is 2d, the other 1d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numpy.vstack`

```
In [22]: import numpy as np

In [23]: a = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])

In [24]: b = np.array([6,7])

In [25]: np.vstack((a.T, b)).T
Out[25]:
array([[1, 2, 6],
       [3, 4, 7]])
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try as shown in [numpy example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) but `b` needs to be of shape `(1, 2)` by just adding array as a inner element of array: `np.array([[6,7]])`

```
a = np.array([[1, 2 ],
              [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[6,7]])

c = np.concatenate((a, b.T), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 6]
 [3 4 7]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [868]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]); b = np.array([6,7])
In [869]: a.shape, b.shape
Out[869]: ((2, 2), (2,))
```

`b` has 1 dimension, it needs 2 to match `a`:

```
In [870]: np.reshape(b,(2,1))
Out[870]: 
array([[6],
       [7]])
```

Now `concatenate` works:

```
In [871]: np.concatenate((a, np.reshape(b,(2,1))), axis=1)
Out[871]: 
array([[1, 2, 6],
       [3, 4, 7]])
```

`np.vstack` works because it adds a new initial dimension if needed.  I added a trailing dimension.

In the long run to use `concatenate` effectively you must learn about dimensions, and how to adjust them if needed.